# Powershell, how to loop through mutliple checkboxes in an array and use the .checked property?

Tags: arrays, loops, powershell, checkbox

I am basically new to powershell, i am currently busy writing an automation tool that remotes into my different load generators machines and edits a few `xml`,`config` and `bat` files as well as fires off certain applications, based on the users selections in the gui.

However I seem to have run into a problem, I have 30 load generator machines and therefor in the GUI im using 30 checkboxes which allow the user to pick which specific load gens they need.
Once the user has finished their selection and clicks continues, I would like to loop through all the checkboxes to determine which boxes have been checked, i could use the manual method and script a statement for all 30 checkboxes but im sure the must be a simpliar method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet here would probably be ShowUI & Splatting ([show-ui.codeplex.com](http://showui.codeplex.com)).

Using this, you'd do something like:

```
$selection = Get-Input @{
    Option1 = [bool]
    Option2 = [bool]
    ...
}

Start-MyCommand @selection
```

Hope this helps